# WPF Datagrid sort index issue

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, indexing

I can't seem to get my head around this.

I've created sample code to demo my issue, hoping someone can direct me to the answer...

The issue is once the datagrid is sorted, the labeled ID and Name no longer matches the selected datagrid item.

I would appriciate your assistance...

Thanks

Jeff

```
<Window x:Class="dgSortTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="dgSortTest" Height="253" Width="403" IsEnabled="True">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="212" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,2,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" RowHeaderWidth="0" AreRowDetailsFrozen="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Label Content="Index: " Name="lblIndex" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="228,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" />
        <Label Content="ID:" Name="lblID" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="228,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" IsEnabled="True" />
        <Label Content="Name: " Name="lblName" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="228,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace dgSortTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
       public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 0, Name = "Jeff" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 1, Name = "Tom" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 2, Name = "Andy" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 3, Name = "Ken" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 4, Name = "Zack" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 5, Name = "Emily" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 6, Name = "Courtney" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 7, Name = "Adam" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 8, Name = "Brenda" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 9, Name = "Bill" });
            people.Add(new Person() { ID = 10, Name = "Joan" });
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = from Person in people select Person;
        }

        private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = dataGrid1.SelectedIndex;
            lblIndex.Content = "Index: " + index.ToString();
            lblID.Content = "ID: " + people[index].ID;
            lblName.Content = "Name: " + people[index].Name;
        } 
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good description of your problem and short sample, +1 for that.

Short answer, to not change to much of your current implementation you can do this.

```
private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Person selectedItem = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as Person;
    int index = dataGrid1.SelectedIndex;
    lblIndex.Content = "Index: " + index.ToString();
    lblID.Content = "ID: " + selectedItem.ID;
    lblName.Content = "Name: " + selectedItem.Name;
}
```

However, I would advice you to bind directly to the SelectedItem instead. Then you won't need the code behind EventHandler.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="228,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Index: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="ID: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.ID}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I must say the first suggestion is much easier to understand, as TBO, I don't yet understand what's going on with xaml. I'm OK with creating the UI with it, but to do most of the coding there, without code behind, has me confused. I'm sure with time, I'll get it.